# How to find out which entity is inside the ObjectStateManager more then once

Tags: entity-framework, objectstatemanager

Hi i get the following error:

> AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict
>   with another  object in the ObjectStateManager.  Make sure that the
>   key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.

Now i'm trying to fix it but i need to pinpoint what entity is giving me trouble so i know where to look.

i know what the error is and i know how to solve it, but i don't know how to find out which entity is double.

Comment: Doesn't matter, i can do both, i'll translate it :)
Working in VB though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the ObjectStateManager to get all the modified entities. the code goes something like this:

```
var lst = context.ObjectStateManager
              .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added |
                                     EntityState.Modified | 
                                     EntityState.Deleted);
var res = lst.GroupBy(c => c.EntityKey).Where(c=> c.Count() > 1);
```